# JPA simple many-to-many with eclipselink

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, eclipselink

I've this ER diagram:

[image]

That was translated into these classes:

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")})
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Collection<UserHasNotify> userHasNotifyCollection;
```

**UserHasNotify.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_has_notify")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "UserHasNotify.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM UserHasNotify u")})
public class UserHasNotify implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected UserHasNotifyPK userHasNotifyPK;
    @Column(name = "has_read")
    private String hasRead;
    @JoinColumn(name = "notify_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Notify notify;
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private User user;
```

**UserHasNotifyPK.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class UserHasNotifyPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "notify_id")
    private int notifyId;
```

**Notify.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notify")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Notify.findAll", query = "SELECT n FROM Notify n")})
public class Notify implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "notify")
    private Collection<UserHasNotify> userHasNotifyCollection;
```

Now, I would to add an entity User and Notify and create a relation between them.
So I've wrote this snippet:

```
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("John");

        Notify notify = new Notify();
        notify.setMessage("Hello World");

        userFacade.create(user);
        notifyFacade.create(notify);

        UserHasNotify uhn = new UserHasNotify();
        uhn.setNotify(notify);
        uhn.setUser(user); 
        uhn.setHasRead("ok");
        uhnFacade.create(uhn);
```

But I receive this error:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'user_id' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO user_has_notify (has_read, user_id, notify_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.test.entity.UserHasNotify[ userHasNotifyPK=null ])
```

Why???????????

Comment: What does `userFacade.create` do ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error may lie in remote communicaton. The fact that you are using the facades implies that you are communicating with your backend remotely.

This would mean that the `user` and `notify` instances you are setting on the `uhn` instance are sent to be persisted on the remote system, while the local instances never receive the generated ids.

To verify and fix this, you can extend your example:

After saving the `user` and `notify`, fetch them from your backend. This should return persisted instances with existing Ids. Then you can use them to store your `uhn` relation.

**EDIT**: I have missed the fact that the `UserHasNotify` is a stateful relationship with an embededd Id. In the code you never set this Id, so the provider misses it.

For this case, I would advise to use an `IdClass` instead of an embededd Id - the mapping is more readable, so you would probably not have mapped the `User` and `Notify` relation twice - once in the embedded PK and once again in the entity ;)

Here is what it would look like:

```
public class UserHasNotifyPK implements Serializable {
    private Notify notify;
    private User user;
    ...
    }
```

.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_has_notify")
@IdClass(UserHasNotifyPK.class)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "UserHasNotify.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM UserHasNotify u")})
public class UserHasNotify implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
    @Column(name = "has_read")
    private String hasRead;
    
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "notify_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Notify notify;
    
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private User user;
```

You can then try the same test again.

Comment: Ok, maybe I've understand. But if I execute User newUser = userFacade.findAll().get(0); Notify newNotify = notifyFacade.findAll().get(0); to fetch latest notify and user. Then I retry to create a uhn with newUser and newNotify objects, but I have the same error.

Comment: @Cecco - I see I have missed an important detail. I have added more info to the answer, please see the edit.

Comment: I've changed with your edit but now I0ve this error: Exception Description: Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [com.test.entity.UserHasNotifyPK] and those of the entity bean class [class com.test.entity.UserHasNotify] must correspond and their types must be the same. Also, ensure that you have specified ID elements for the corresponding attributes in XML and/or an @Id on the corresponding fields or properties of the entity class.

Comment: @Cecco - please excuse my misleading advice. I was too inattentive (-.-). The fields in teh PK class must be of the same type and have the same name as the id fields in the entity. I have corrected the Id class.

Comment: Ok, you're right and I've fixed it, but now I've a new error. Sorry, but I'm a newbie of JPA eclipselink...Exception [EclipseLink-46] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [user_has_notify.notify_id].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.test.entity.UserHasNotify --> [DatabaseTable(user_has_notify)])

Comment: @Cecco - I am not quite sure what would the correct solution would be, but the source of the error is that the provider cannot update either side of the relationship. Setting the `insertable` and `updateable` attributes on the id fields of `UserHasNotify` to `true` should fix that.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Solution for it?